# Relating the column rank/row rank of a matrix to the dimension of the image of a linear map.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a matrix $A$, a linear mapping $T:\Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^m$, I am struggling to understand why after row reducing $A$ to RREF (row reduced echelon form), that the number of leading $1$'s in the resulting matrix is equivalent to the dimension of the image of $T$. How can I relate these two concepts rigorously?

Comment: Do you know the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: @manthanomen yes. But I am not sure why the dimension of the image of the map is equivalent to the column rank of the corresponding matrix.

Comment: The columns of the matrix show you where the basis elements get sent (and thus determine the entire map). So if there are $k$ linearly independent column vectors, the image of your map is spanned by $k$ vectors, so it has dimension $k$.

Comment: OK! great! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to see that the image is the span of the columns.  For  $$\begin {bmatrix}  a_{11}\dots a_{1n}\\\vdots \\ a_{m1} \dots a_{mn}\end {bmatrix}\cdot \begin  {bmatrix} v_1\\\vdots\\v_n\end {bmatrix}=v_1\begin {bmatrix}a_{11}\\\vdots \\a_{m1}\end {bmatrix}+v_2\begin  {bmatrix} a _{12}\\\vdots \\a_{m2}\end {bmatrix}\cdots +v_n\begin  {bmatrix} a_{1n}\\\vdots \\a_{mn} \end {bmatrix}$$...

Hence the dimension of the image is the column rank.  Also,  there is a theorem that the column rank equals the row rank...  This number is called the *rank of the matrix*...