# Finding values that doesn't span a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For example the vector space $\Bbb R^3$.

I think that's a pretty good starting point. If I had three vectors, how would I go on acquiring the values that doesn't exist for $\Bbb R^3$?

Help would be appreciated.

*F*

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  What do you mean by "the values that [don't] exist for $\mathbb{R}^3$?    Also in the title,  what are "values that [don't] span a vector space"?  I can't understand this question at all.

Comment: if you have three vectors but they lie in the same plane, they do not span all of $R^3.$ In turn, this is accomplished by having a nontrivial linear relation among the three: vectors $u,v,w$  with real coefficients $a,b,c$ that are not all zero, with relation $au + bv + cw = 0$  as vectors.

Comment: One quick way is to take some $u,v$ and then construct $w=u+v$

Comment: Hey, for example if I have the vectors $(1, -α, β), (α, -1, -α), (0, α - 1, β)$. 

I would like to find values for $α$ and $β$ such that they do not span $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: You can put the vectors as the columns of a matrix and reduce. The three vectors span all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ if and only if the reduced matrix has 3 pivot columns if and only if the reduced row echelon form is the identity matrix.

Comment: I am sorry, I appreciate the comment, but I don't quite understand. Like calculus, I am also trying to get back into linear algebra. It seems I have forgotten some concepts. I would appreciate if you could elaborate more, for my sake, if you will. Thanks.

Comment: You can see a post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3658799/understanding-the-column-space/3658875#3658875) about the column space and how it relates to matrix multiplication. To say the 3 column vectors span $\mathbb{R}^3$ means the column space of the matrix $A$ is $\mathbb{R}^3$. Since row operations [preserve linear dependence among columns](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354362/why-do-elementary-row-operations-preserve-linear-dependence-between-matrix-colum), row reduction is justified if you just want to find the dimension of the span of the columns (i.e. rank).